# Вызов метода второго класса через свойство первого класса

Tags: классы, php

Привет!)

Условие:

в классе_1 есть такая строчка: `$this->module = $_GET['module'];`

В последствии необходимо вызвать метод класса_2. Обычный вызов происходит вот так: `$this->класс_2->метод();`

Задача:

чтобы вызываемый "метод()" равнялся `$this->module`.

Проблема:

нельзя произвести вызов таким образом `$this->класс_2->$this->module()`

Пояснение:

Я прекрасно понимаю и осознаю, почему нельзя сделать `$this->класс_2->$this->module()`. Задаю вопрос здесь, скорее, чтобы убедится, что решения, кроме как создания обычной переменной и дублирования туда `$_GET['module']` или вызова напрямую с `$_GET['module']`, нет. То есть или вот так:

```
$module = $_GET['module'];
$this->класс_2->$module();
```

или вот так:

```
$this->класс_2->$_GET['module']();
```

Все ли правильно и верно?

Спасибо! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для вызова произвольной функции/метода нужна функция `call_user_func()` или `call_user_func_array()`.

```
call_user_func(array($this->clazz2Instance, $this->module));
```

Есть еще `call_user_func()`, но она вряд ли понадобится.

Comment: Еще `ReflectionMethod` же есть для подобных манипуляций.

Comment: @Kitten, через рефлексию можно вызвать, конечно, но она не для "поседневных" вызовов существует.

Comment: Спасибо! К вечеру как-то в сторону функций мозг не повернулся, хотя такое сплошь и рядом =)

Answer (score 3):

Получить методы можно от наследуемого класса, то есть

```
class Foo {
    public function foo() {
        return true;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    public function bar() {
        parent::foo();
    }
}
```

Либо явно создав объект.

[**Документация**](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

Comment: Там у двух классов разные родители. Но спасибо за ответ! =)